# Sorting QTableWidget Items Numerically

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7, pyqt4, qtablewidget

Using QTableWidget within PyQt4 when sorting is enabled, the items are sorted as strings.

variable = [1,2,3,4,5,11,22,33]

produces order

1
11
2
22
3
33
4
5

I am currently using the code below to fill the table

```
tableWidgetData.setItem(0, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(variable))
```

I have tried as I thought the variables are only sorted as string because they are strings

```
tableWidgetData.setItem(0, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(int(variable)))
```

But this wasn't possible. Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anything pass variable in `QtGui.QTableWidgetItem` constructor, I must be `QtCore.QString` ot python sring only.

To fix it, Create your custom `QtGui.QTableWidgetItem` and implement check case less than (or we know in python is [`object.__lt__(self, other)`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html)) by overide[`bool QTableWidgetItem.__lt__ (self, QTableWidgetItem other)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidgetitem.html#__lt__).

Example;

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class QCustomTableWidgetItem (QtGui.QTableWidgetItem):
    def __init__ (self, value):
        super(QCustomTableWidgetItem, self).__init__(QtCore.QString('%s' % value))

    def __lt__ (self, other):
        if (isinstance(other, QCustomTableWidgetItem)):
            selfDataValue  = float(self.data(QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString())
            otherDataValue = float(other.data(QtCore.Qt.EditRole).toString())
            return selfDataValue < otherDataValue
        else:
            return QtGui.QTableWidgetItem.__lt__(self, other)

class QCustomTableWidget (QtGui.QTableWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomTableWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setColumnCount(2)
        self.setRowCount(5)
        for row in range(self.rowCount()):
            self.setItem(row, 0, QCustomTableWidgetItem(random.random() * 1e4))
            self.setItem(row, 1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(QtCore.QString(65 + row)))
        self.setSortingEnabled(True)

myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication([])
myQCustomTableWidget = QCustomTableWidget()
myQCustomTableWidget.show()
sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you, creating a custom QtGui.QTableWidgetItem was the way to do it. It's working great now